# Auto increment a non-primary key field in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, primary-key, auto-increment

In a RoR migration, how do I auto increment a non-primary-key field? I'd like to do this in the db definition, and not in the model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to execute an SQL statement.

```
statement = "ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `id` `id` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT" 
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(statement)
```

you can entry manually in your migration

Note this is just an example. The final SQL statement syntax depends on the database.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming by your answer that Rails does not provide a way to do this without direct execution of a SQL statement?  I would expect something like: `t.integer :auto_i, :auto_increment => true` to work (but it does not).

Comment: yes  Rails does not provide :auto_increment keyword in migrations

Comment: And if you want to all keywords or other good things in Rails then . " rubymine IDE for ROR " would be so useful. I am using for last 6 months.

Comment: Note that this is `mysql` specific solution. Postgres doesn't support `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Jump into this question for Postgres solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement