# How to increment data on new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm on Ruby on Rails and I have a integer column called `position`.

What's the best way to assign a `position` value which is bigger than the the biggest on its table, when creating a new record?

At the moment i'm doing this:

```rb
# db/migrate/entry_migration
create_table :entries do |t|
    t.integer          :position
    #...
end
```

```rb
# app/views/entries/_form
<%= simple_form_for @entry do |f| %>
  <% if @entry.new_record? && @entries.order('position').last.present? %>
    <%= f.input :position, as: :hidden, value: @entries.order('position').last.position + 1 %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.input :position, as: :hidden %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: maybe `SERIAL`izing `position` column might help you. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

`ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN position SERIAL`

Comment: @marmeladze this does the trick, but then would it be possible to change that value when it comes to rearrange entries position? Or am I bound to that initial value?

Comment: no you can force values any time you want.  but if you give more details, about your table, some seed data, i might propose better solution. either with rails or postgres own itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`acts_as_list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) is what you are looking for, it will do it gracefully..

If you don't want gem dependency, there are two things I can think of,

**Using callback:**

```
before_create :set_position

private

def set_position
  position = YourModel.order(:position).pluck(:position).last.to_i + 1
end
```

**Autoincrement**

`autoincrement` is another better option since it will take care of itself at db level and you dnt need to bother yourself. In your model create migration,

```
...
t.integer :position
...
execute "CREATE SEQUENCE your_models_position_seq OWNED BY your_models.position INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1"
```

**UPDATE**

To respect input value,

```
position = YourModel.order(:position).pluck(:position).last.to_i + 1 unless position.to_i > 0
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181450/add-autoincrement-via-migration-in-rails)

Comment: I'm trying the *callback* solution as it gives me more room for customization.

Comment: `before_create` method gave me *no method* error so I had to use `before_action ... only: [:create]`.

Comment: Which rails version u using? N check my update to prevent always incrementing value and respect value from user

Comment: I also had to add fallback if no records are present in my Model.

Comment: I'm using Ruby on Rails `5.0.1`

Comment: If no records are present, you get nil and so, just use `nil.to_i` will do the trick..

Comment: `before_create` should work then, you need to write that in `model` and not `controller`