# Standardized way of AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: sql, standards

Is there a standardized way I can create a table in SQL with a column (lets call it ID) that is auto incremental so that I can basically use it in all databases?

(e.g. standardized in SQL-92)
If so - how? If not, why? I think auto_increment is a very often used property so I thought it would be very important to standardize it…

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp my-sql is auto increment . sql server is identity, access is AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no standard for auto-increment. Oracle for example offers sequences only. You can create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to simulate auto-increment behaviour however there is no native implementation. [PostgreSQL is different yet again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry. There is `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL, but e.g. in MS SQL this is called `IDENTITY` and `SERIAL` in PGSQL. Many things are not really standardized in SQL - and most are in the schema creating area.

It's a mess, but you can use stuff like e.g. Hibernate/NHibernate to try to use a single code base.

**Update**: Few year later there is a more standard way that *some* DBMS support (e.g. PG SQL from version 10.0, so from October 2017):

- GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY -- the value has a default auto incrementation, but you can insert your own.
- GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY -- forbids inserting own values (in a standard query, might be overriden)

This is something that should work in [PG SQL 10+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtable.html), [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-warehouse?topic=concepts-auto-numbering-identifier-columns), [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/22.3/sqlreferencefornosql/example-updating-identity-defined-generated-default.html):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS simple_test;
CREATE TABLE simple_test(
    s_id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
);
```

Note however that this will not work in Microsoft SQL Server (not even in MS SQL Server 2022). [MSSQL does *not* support the generated keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16). MySQL/MariaDb has generated columns, but [MariaDb does *not* support the identity syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/).

So yeah, 10 years later the answer is kind of the same really -- it is still a mess and you should probably use a framework for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use so-called *identity columns*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo(id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
```

This is in the SQL standard and should be supported by PostgreSQL 10 and Oracle:

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns/#comment-248607

Comment: I think this is the correct answer as far as standards go. Unfortunately, with SQL, databases are generally not fully standards compliant.

Comment: PG10 is from Oct 2017. That is 4.5 years after this question ;-). And it is still not supported in MariaDB/MySQL, so not a replacement for `AUTO_INCREMENT` in any way.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle you need to create a SEQUENCE

SQLite uses it for rowid and a synonym of it e.g. RowIdSyn INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: In recent version of Oracle, you can use the standard "GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY"