# How to add column with auto incremented value for added rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a main table X with columns a,b which I wish to copy to other table Y.
Y has 3 columns: a,b,z where z should be auto incremented - 0,1,2...
I want to be able to do

```
INSERT INTO Y(a,b,z) select a,b from X WHERE ....
```

so i actually have subquery with only a,b and I want them to be added with values 0,1,2,3... in the new table Y.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `row_number()`.  Subtract one to start at zero:

```
insert  into y
        (a,b,z) 
select  a
,       b 
,       row_number() over (order by a, b) - 1
from    X
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you would use

```
Id       Int          NoNullable Identity(1,1)
```

For [Postgres auroincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement) use `SERIAL`