# Generate sequence numbers on PostgreSQL integer column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table on PostgreSQL and 1000 rows in it. I have an integer column in my table that is empty. I want to populate `newid` with sequential, unique numbers a bit like a primary key.

```
Product
-------------------------
id  name  newid  size
60   ....  null   L
72   ....  null   M
83   ....  null   xl
84   ....  null   S
85   ...
```

How can I write a query that update my `newid` column.

```
Product
-------------------------
id  name  newid  size
60   ....  1      L
72   ....  2      M
83   ....  3      xl
84   ....  4      S
85   ...
```

Comment: Please elaborate.  It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results can be a big help.

Comment: What's wrong with the id column?

Comment: newid column will be generated new integer values .

Comment: Are you looking for `ROW_NUMBER()` ?

Comment: Why should the value L get number 1 and value M the number 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Autoincrement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using `JOIN` or subquery.  The idea is to calculate the new id using `row_number()` and then bring that value into each row:

```
with newvals (
      select p.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from product p
     )
update product p
    set newid = (select seqnum from newvals nv where nv.id = p.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
update mytable set
newid = id + 1000000
```