# Unique annotation @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations, crud

What I want to do is add (POST) resource with automaticly generated id. 
I added annotations and my model looks like this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String brand;
```

Question is why when I POST some value without id for example:

```
{
    "brand": "sony"
}
```

I GET automaticly id = 0:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "brand": "sony"
}
```

And if I post more resources without calling id they all have id = 0 (so it's not unique).

What I do wrong?

Comment: Which DB you using?

Comment: embedded called h2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I GET automaticly id = 0:

That is because you are using a [primitive data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `long` and its default value is `0`.

And the serialization-deserialization of such fields would end up appending the *default value* of the primitive data types if not assigned explicitly.

In cases where you need to exclude such fields when there is not value set, you might intend to use [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)(reference type) instead.

Comment: Changing type for Long creates an error when i try to GET resources.
"error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
    "message": "Could not write content: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[3]->spring.degath.model.Phone[\"id\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[3]->spring.degath.model.Phone[\"id\"])",
    "path": "/phones/"
}

Comment: @degath  As pointed in the answer *where you need to exclude such fields* is when you shall use `Long` and then mark such fields with annotations similar to `Include.NonNull`. Or else you can continue to make use of `long` with a default value of 0. There isn't any harm in it either. Depends on your API implementation further.

Comment: Oh, I understand now why it is a default value 0, but the question is what to do to get auto incremented id while POST request (I expected that annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY will do it for me, but seems like I've got wrong thinking)

Comment: @degath Well that wasn't stated in the question though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388919/auto-generate-id-in-spring-mvc can help you in that case.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm accepting your answer obviously and again thanks for a lot of forbearance. You made my day :)