# Auto Generated Id instead of null or default 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Like in a title, I'm trying to find a way to get auto genrated id when POST resource.

I use embaded h2 or hsqldb database.

What I was already testing?

- I changed strategy for identity (I know that AUTO should be the same as identity, but tried anyway)
- I changed long for Long (GET result: default 0 changed for default null)
- I readed a lot of posts for example this answer looks solid [similar post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36389151/6701496) but I think my case is different (should I really delete id from POST method?)

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
package spring.degath.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import spring.degath.data.PhoneRepository;
import spring.degath.model.Phone;
import spring.degath.services.PhoneService;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class PhoneController {

    @Autowired
    private PhoneService phoneService;

    @Autowired
    private PhoneRepository phoneRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/phones")
    public List<Phone> getAllPhones(){
        return phoneService.getAllPhones();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/phones/{id}")
    public Phone getPhone(@PathVariable Long id){
        return phoneService.getPhone(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/phones")
    public void addPhone(@RequestBody Phone phone){
        phoneService.addPhone(phone);
    }

}
```

Service:

```
package spring.degath.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import spring.degath.data.PhoneRepository;
import spring.degath.model.Phone;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PhoneService {

    private List<Phone> phones;

    @Autowired
    private PhoneRepository phoneRepository;

    public List<Phone> getAllPhones(){
        return phones;
    }

    public Phone getPhone(final Long id){
        return phoneRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        phones.add(phone);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void initDataForTesting() {

        phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();

        Phone phone1 = new Phone((long) 1,"nokia");
        Phone phone2 = new Phone((long) 2,"sony");
        Phone phone3 = new Phone((long) 3,"samsung");

        phones.add(phone1);
        phones.add(phone2);
        phones.add(phone3);

    }

}
```

Repository:

```
package spring.degath.data;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import spring.degath.model.Phone;

public interface PhoneRepository extends CrudRepository<Phone, String> {

    Phone findById(Long id);

}
```

Model:

```
package spring.degath.model;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    private String brand;

    public Phone(){
    }

    public Phone(Long id, String brand) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
}
```

I have no clue what to do. Please share your knowledge.

Best wishes,
Degath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity Strategy AUTO is correct, you just missing save phone to the database with **phoneRepository.save()** that's why it didn't generate the ID. All you do above is just adding to the list and retrieve back from the list. Try this:

```
@Service
public class PhoneService {

    private List<Phone> phones;

    @Autowired
    private PhoneRepository phoneRepository;

    public List<Phone> getAllPhones(){
        return phones;
    }

    public Phone getPhone(final Long id){
        return phoneRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        phones.add(phone);
        phoneRepository.save(phone);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void initDataForTesting() {

        phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();

        Phone phone1 = new Phone((long) 1,"nokia");
        Phone phone2 = new Phone((long) 2,"sony");
        Phone phone3 = new Phone((long) 3,"samsung");

        phones.add(phone1);
        phones.add(phone2);
        phones.add(phone3);
        phoneRepository.save(phones);
    }

}
```