# auto-increment column in PostgreSQL on the fly?

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering if it is possible to add an auto-increment integer field **on the fly**, i.e. without defining it in a `CREATE TABLE` statement?

For example, I have a statement:

```
SELECT 1 AS id, t.type FROM t;
```

and I am can I change this to

```
SELECT some_nextval_magic AS id, t.type FROM t;
```

I need to create the auto-increment field on the fly in the `some_nextval_magic` part because the result relation is a **temporary** one during the construction of a bigger SQL statement. And the value of `id` field is not really important as long as it is unique.

I search around here, and the answers to related questions (e.g. [PostgreSQL Autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)) mostly involving specifying `SERIAL` or using `nextval` in `CREATE TABLE`. But I don't necessarily want to use `CREATE TABLE` or `VIEW` (unless I have to). There are also some discussions of `generate_series()`, but I am not sure whether it applies here.

**-- Update --**

My motivation is illustrated in this [GIS.SE answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144056/34474) regarding the PostGIS extension. The original query was:

```
CREATE VIEW buffer40units AS
SELECT 
   g.path[1] as gid, 
   g.geom::geometry(Polygon, 31492) as geom 
FROM
   (SELECT 
     (ST_Dump(ST_UNION(ST_Buffer(geom, 40)))).* 
   FROM point
) as g;
```

where `g.path[1] as gid` is an id field "required for visualization in QGIS". I believe the only requirement is that it is **integer** and **unique** across the table. I encountered some errors when running the above query when the `g.path[]` array is empty.

While trying to fix the array in the above query, this thought came to me:

Since the `gid` value does not matter anyways, is there an auto-increment function that can be used here instead?

Comment: Postgresql has CREATE SEQUENCE. You can get incrementing numbers from those.

Comment: @tinlyx Can you give more details on the uniqueness you require ... be it locally within a query versus globally across queries

Comment: Please post your code. You've been around SO long enough to know how to ask a proper question. There are various solutions depending on how your statement is constructed. Without more information you will get nothing but wild hunches.

Comment: Do you require an integer? If not md5(row_to_json(x)::text) would work as a key (or a pg_crypto hash of some kind)

Comment: @JoeLove and Patrick, please see my update regarding the use case/requirement.

Comment: @tinlyx Do you need the `id` to be consistent across different executions of this query?  That is, should a particular `geom` always be assigned the same `id`, or not?

Answer (score 16):

If you wish to have an `id` field that assigns a unique integer to each row in the output, then use the [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) window function:

```
select 
    row_number() over () as id, 
    t.type from t;
```

The generated `id` will only be unique within each execution of the query.  Multiple executions will not generate new unique values for `id`.

Comment: @tinlyx: How unique does the number have to be? Just within the query itself? Or across multiple runs of the query?

Comment: @Thilo, ideally, unique across concurrent runs if possible.

Comment: Is order important? If not, just use a hash function

Comment: this does not create a unique id when combined with PostGIS `ST_DUMP`.