# Adding an index column to an existing table in postrges sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with data that has no unique data anywhere on the table. I want to create a column that would serve as a unique identifier.

How do I add a new primary key column to the existing table?

Comment: Index and primary key syntax is readily available on Google and other Stack Overflow posts. A primary key is a unique value in the table. If you don't have a unique ID on the table anywhere, you can't use a primary key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement

Comment: That is precisely my question. How do I create a column that can be used as a primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following SQL statement to create a unique identifier (Primiry Key) in to your existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD  key_column SERIAL;
```

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres

Comment: One can also try this.

ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN key_column BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;

Comment: I am using postrges for this project.

Comment: I ran the code you suggested and received the following error, "Cannot add column with primary key constraint".