# Scoped sequence in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.4

I want to generate unique invoice number per team. 
I want to have it generated automatically by postgresql database.

I looked at the documentation for creating sequences in postgresql docs. However, I could not find out how I would specify that, the numbers should be unique on team_id level in the table.

Not sure if this is even possible.

Currently, I am creating the next number through code like this
`team.invoices.maximum(:invoice_number).to_i +`

To deal with concurrency, I have created unique index on the invoices table (team_id, invoice_number). This will prevent duplicate numbers being created on team level.

But, I wanted this to be generated from postgresql itself.

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6632280/7998591 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/11496945/7998591

Comment: Are the invoice numbers per team have no gaps ?
Would you like the database to create the invoice number? did you have a look on Default attribute? finally, did you try PostgreSQl domain type.

Comment: @kaushikNayak, using an 'OWNED BY' attribute while creating a Sequence won't assign unique sequences for each team which is my current requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnot find a direct solution from postgresql. 
However, I found out this gem called [sequenced](https://github.com/derrickreimer/sequenced) which helped me create scoped sequences supporting concurrent transactions.

Comment: same problem, I couldn't find any solution to optimize it, thanks for your answer.