# DbUtils type conversion issue during object serialization

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, flyway, apache-commons-dbutils

I am using DbUtils to handle interchangeability between PostgreSQL and MySQL. I kind of expected this to be an issue but was hoping there would be a clean way to handle type conversion. I am using Flyway to do my migrations, so I have to write my schema as standard as possible to support all the different types of relational databases it supports, with PostgreSQL and MySQL being a primary focus (for now).

Here is a basic schema that I am working with:

```
CREATE TABLE access (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  apikey varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  apikey_type int DEFAULT '0',
  apikey_enabled smallint DEFAULT '1',
  topicid int DEFAULT NULL,
  collection varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  lastseen timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

Here is what the POJO class looks like:

```
public class ClientAccessRecord {

    private BigInteger id;

    private Integer apiKeyType;

    private boolean enabled;

    private String topic;

    private int topicId;

    private String lastRecordTime;

    private int lastRecordId;

    private String collection;
}
```

I am struggling with two fields: `id` and `apikey_enabled`. I have specified `id` to be `SERIAL` because PostgreSQL does not support `AUTO_INCREMENT` directive. However, `SERIAL` means `UNSIGNED INT` in PostgreSQL and `UNSIGNED BIGINT` in MySQL, resulting in a conversion failure in DbUtils `BeanHandler`. Furthermore, the `apikey_enabled` fails in PostgreSQL but not in MySQL. It treats it as a boolean in MySQL while PostgreSQL is trying to convert into an int.

I am at a loss here. What are the best practices when trying to standardize schema's? Should I avoid DbUtils object mapping and stick to the more tedious, albeit more control, approach of manually setting these values?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `SERIAL` in PostgreSQL as per:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6632280

Which means you can use any data type...