# Add incrementing value to the column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table which contains `69000 records`. Now, how to add a new column(say index) which should contain the `value 1 for 1st row, 2 for 2nd row ....etc`.

I want the following result

```
   id      name      index
 --------------------------
 9796896   sandy       1
 796869    raj         2
```

Comment: You can add the new column as IDENTITY column.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with Oracle if you are using PostgreSQL? (Also 'index' seems like a poor choice name for a column... it wouldn't be legal in Oracle, unless quoted.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)

Comment: Check this out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_autoincrement.htm#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the column and update it with something like that :

```
with cte as
(
   select *
       , rank() over (order by id desc) as ranker
   from test
)
update test
   set index = ranker
from cte
where cte.id = test.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Tablename
    ADD COLUMN index int               
        GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;
```

Comment: generated columns ? Are they not available only for version 12 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use identity column of the oracle:

```
alter table your_Table add index_ number GENERATED by default as IDENTITY;
```

also, you can add the column and then assign value to it:

```
alter table your_Table add index_ number;

update your_Table tt
set tt.index_  =  (select rn from (
select row_number() over (order by id desc) rn
from your_Table t
) t where t.id = tt.id)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked nicely for me running postgres 9.6:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN index BIGSERIAL ;
```

Short one liner and it keeps on auto-incrementing in future inserts.

Although I think the count started at zero.  I'll update answer after I checked.