# set id unique to username

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

i have a POSTS table in postgres whose schema looks like below

```
create table posts(postid int ,postname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 createdby VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (postname),
 CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY(createdby) REFERENCES users(username) on DELETE CASCADE);
```

maybe a noob question but i dont want the postid to be always set by the user, i want it to be incremental to a user.
lets say for example i have 2 users each of whom are adding 2 posts,

so i want to store that in db as

```
postid.    postname.    createdby
1           hi           user1
2           second       user1
1           hi           user2
2           second       user2
```

is something like this possible for the postid to get autoincremented without me having to insert it that way?

i.e a postid and name can be similar to different users

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)

Comment: autoincrement keeps on increase the postid,  i want it to be autoincrement for each user @maio290

Comment: The way you'd like to post it into your database is a weird approach which doesn't make much sense to me. You have defined postname as primary key, but the values aren't even unique in your example. The most common approach would be to autoincrement the postid and set it as primary key. Or you use a composite key of createdBy and postname (?!?) with its constraints.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table posts(
    postid int,
    postname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    createdby VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (postname));

create function tgf_posts_bi() returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    seq_name text;
begin
    seq_name := format('seq_posts_%s', new.createdby);
    execute format('create sequence if not exists %I start with 1', seq_name);
    new.postid := nextval((quote_ident(seq_name))::regclass);
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger tg_posts_bi
before insert on posts
for each row execute procedure tgf_posts_bi();

insert into posts(postname, createdby) values
    ('foo', 'John'),
    ('bar', 'Jack Daniel'),
    ('baz', 'Jack Daniel'),
    ('win', 'John'),
    ('amp', 'John'),
    ('M$ media mplayer', 'Mary');

table posts;

postid | postname         | createdby  
-----: | :--------------- | :----------
     1 | foo              | John       
     1 | bar              | Jack Daniel
     2 | baz              | Jack Daniel
     2 | win              | John       
     3 | amp              | John       
     1 | M$ media mplayer | Mary
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7446fb61243fbc29c64bbc6e0e41de97)

Comment: but when i add the same postname for different createby, it still throws an error
insert into posts (postname,createdby) values('foo','test');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "posts_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (postname)=(foo) already exists.

Comment: @sai Yes because of `PRIMARY KEY (postname)` You need to choose another primary key for the data provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of your problem, and this may be radically oversimplified, but as I understand it you only want one record per post/user.  If this is the case, your primary key should be both the `postname` and the `createdby` fields, which would guarantee only one record per user/post:

```
create table posts (
  postid int,
  postname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  createdby VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  constraint posts_pk PRIMARY KEY (postname, createdby),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY(createdby) REFERENCES users(username) on DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Then, when you insert, instead of a plain insert, you want to do an upsert.  This says insert the record if it doesn't exist; otherwise update it:

```
insert into posts (postid, postname, createdby)
values (1, 'hi', 'user1')
on conflict on constraint posts_pk
do
  update
  set
    postid = posts.postid + 1
```

I can't help but feel something is missing from the problem statement, but from what I glean I am hopeful this will help.

Comment: You should probably add that this implies that a post (?) cannot be posted again by the same user. That sounds a little bit odd for me (hence my comment).

Comment: @maio290 - the use case is very unclear to me, so I admit I'm grasping at straws on this one

Comment: just edited the question, so the post can be same for different users

Comment: @sai - I still don't understand.  Maybe if you can add current statements, the current behavior and then be specific about desired behavior...  that should be a good starting point.  What it does now vs what I want it to do (and why)