# How to create a game_id variable for team / opponent data in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

looking for some help on how to create a game_id variable in SQL.  I'm working on an nba project and I can manipulate the data into team, date, opponent format where every team has a row for each game they play.  A game_id variable would make my life easier for other work in the project but I don't know how to create it.

The variable itself can start from 1 or 100000, doesn't matter.  I just need it to uniquely identify every game that is being played.

Below is an example table + data you can create to see my dilemma.  Ideally the LAL and GSW rows would both have the same game_id, and the BKN and MIL rows would have the same game_id.

```
CREATE TABLE basketball_data (
    team text,
    dategame date,
    opponent text
);

INSERT INTO basketball_data (team, dategame, opponent)
VALUES ('GSW', '2021-10-19', 'LAL');

INSERT INTO basketball_data (team, dategame, opponent)
VALUES ('LAL', '2021-10-19', 'GSW');

INSERT INTO basketball_data (team, dategame, opponent)
VALUES ('BKN', '2021-10-19', 'MIL');

INSERT INTO basketball_data (team, dategame, opponent)
VALUES ('MIL', '2021-10-19', 'BKN');
```

Anyone have an idea of what would be a way of creating a variable like this?  If it makes a difference, I'm working in PostgreSQL.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)

Comment: @maio290's link is good. The accepted answer is to use a `serial` column, but these days the recommended way is to use `identity` as described in the [fourth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035250/9705687) of that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following using DENSE_RANK as a window function:

**Retrieving a game id during queries**

```
SELECT
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY 
              dategame,(
                CASE
                    WHEN team < opponent THEN CONCAT(team,opponent)
                    ELSE CONCAT(opponent,team)
                END
              )
     ) as game_id,     
     team,
     dategame,
     opponent
FROM 
     basketball_data;
```

| game_id | team | dategame | opponent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BKN | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | MIL |
| 1 | MIL | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | BKN |
| 2 | GSW | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | LAL |
| 2 | LAL | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | GSW |

---

**Creating a new table with the same data and game id**

```
CREATE TABLE basketball_data_with_game_id AS 
SELECT
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY 
              dategame,(
                CASE
                    WHEN team < opponent THEN CONCAT(team,opponent)
                    ELSE CONCAT(opponent,team)
                END
              )
     ) as game_id,     
     team,
     dategame,
     opponent
FROM 
     basketball_data;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

```
SELECT * FROM basketball_data_with_game_id;
```

| game_id | team | dategame | opponent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BKN | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | MIL |
| 1 | MIL | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | BKN |
| 2 | GSW | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | LAL |
| 2 | LAL | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | GSW |

---

**Updating the existing table to have the game id**

```
ALTER TABLE basketball_data
ADD game_id INT DEFAULT 0;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

```
UPDATE basketball_data
SET game_id = n.game_id
FROM (
SELECT
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY 
              dategame,(
                CASE
                    WHEN team < opponent THEN CONCAT(team,opponent)
                    ELSE CONCAT(opponent,team)
                END
              )
     ) as game_id,     
     team,
     dategame,
     opponent
FROM 
     basketball_data
) n
WHERE basketball_data.game_id=0 AND
      basketball_data.team=n.team AND
      basketball_data.dategame=n.dategame AND
      basketball_data.opponent=n.opponent;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

```
SELECT * FROM basketball_data;
```

| team | dategame | opponent | game_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BKN | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | MIL | 1 |
| MIL | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | BKN | 1 |
| GSW | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | LAL | 2 |
| LAL | 2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z | GSW | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r7vCv4U2iDX7LwQxSfpsBH/1)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: great solution!  the first option works for my use case but thanks for including the others as well in case the table needs to be recreated or updated